How can I find where SQLite stores data when using an in-memory database (:memory:)?
The memory consumption of a Node.js server process using an SQLite in-memory database decreased from 1.5 GB to 50 MB in Task Manager, while the SQLite database still contains 1 GB of data. The database size was found using this query: SELECT (page_count - freelist_count) * page_size AS size FROM pragma_page_count(), pragma_freelist_count(), pragma_page_size().
where sqlite storing 1gb data in windows ?

As it is "in memory" from sqlite's point of view, you should look for the other OS resources (e.g. like physical ram vs. swap memory). This stuff is handled by the OS you are using and not by sqlite.
